Canonical way to export an icon font into SF Symbols
SFSymbols is the official icon library that ships with Apple's SDKs. While being of very high quality and flexible, it's pretty short on symbols, compared to other libraries.
I wonder whether there is a programmatic way to convert an icon font into a custom SF-Symbol collection.

Sure - but not a particularly simple task. The Assets catalog is a folder/file structure. Extract the glyphs from the "icon font" as paths... write them out as .svg files (based on SF-Symbol template)... create folders inside Assets.xcassets... write .json file and .svg into the folders.
